# why is my richfaces showing without css?

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to add a richfaces calendar to an already running jsf internal website.
the calendar is not showing as it is in the demo, and after searching I found that this file: `http://localhost:8080/abcd/faces/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_both.xcss/DATB/eAF7sqpgb-jyGdIAFrMEaw__` is not being loaded (0 size).

I'm not sure what is the problem. I'm assuming its a sort of conflict but I can't put my hand on it at the moment.

any thoughts/ideas on how to solve this?

P.S. my web.xml has the following lines:

```
<context-param>  
<param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>  
<param-value>blueSky</param-value>  
</context-param>

<context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
      <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
   <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: is it only the CSS which is not loaded or the whole richfaces component does not work?

Comment: @balazs-maria-nemeth Richfaces works, I can see the  calendar input box and calendar widget open when I click on the box, its just the css that is empty.